# Laravel development server doesn't work windows

Tags: php, git, laravel, serve

I installed laravel on my computer, which works fine through PhpStorm, the laravel commands in the Git command prompt, as well as the composer and the php artisan ones work just fine.
But for the command

```
php artisan serve
```

it gives me an address which doesn't work

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

if I try to access the address, it says that "this site can't be reached". by the way, I'm using Chrome
why this may be and how could I make it to work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try php artisan serve --port=8080 and then go to localhost:8080. Also I recomand using vagrant/homestead https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead

Comment: thank you, it worked! i may consider homestead in the future, for the moment i'm wishing to learn the basics of laravel and i'm using xampp for this

Comment: if you use wamp you can add a host in wamp and access the website in the browser with an address you give ex: laravel.dev. That way you can run as many websites as you wan tin parallel (https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Laragon for developing laravel or even any php app on windows. It'll set up a very easy to use and fast development environment. I have been using it for over a year now. Get it here: https://laragon.org/

This app is specific to windows users. Some of the features include;

```
Cmder
Git
Node.js
NPM
SSH
Putty
PHP 7 & 5.6 (Easily switchable with one click)
Activate/deactivate PHP extensions on the fly
xDebug
Composer
Apache
MariaDB/MySQL
phpMyAdmin
Full Lumen and Laravel support
Auto create virtual hosts
Mail Catcher - Laragon will show a small window on the bottom right of your screen and help you quickly view content of the generated email
Mail Sender - You can use mail() function to send mail to the Internet easily and effortlessly
Mail Analyzer: Analyze what happens when an email is sent and show helpful information to make sure that your email configurations are correct.
ngrok - allows connections from the Internet to the local server
```

This is tutorial about laragon and laravel 5.4: 
    http://www.danfletcherblog.ca/2017/02/install-laravel-5-4-windows-fast-using-laragon-%E2%9C%94/

This is a video tutorial of the post: https://youtu.be/pHQOdXY2AZU?list=PL0Nx259JjLcGqXg5kpTifqQ9GFoQ2qGPy

Comment: Please make your answer more clear and add the benefits laragon and why is it better than say homestead, valet or just plain old wamp. It might help someone else in the future.